# Default locale settings formatting a datetime instance

Tags: c#, datetime, iis, model-view-controller, format

I need to use `string.Format("{0}", DateTimeInstance)` in a server application running on iis. I was sure that the format applied was the one of the server but i find out that the date is formatted as dd/MM/yyyy... some times and MM/dd/yyyy other times. I am guessing this depends by the client (the browser connected) settings. Is this possible? If yes, can I override this behaviour and force the server settings, without specifing a format?

Comment: How about reading the documentation for [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906224(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Can you be less sarcastic and more useful? I have studied the documentetion and couldn't find anything about the default culture settings applied in a web application.

Comment: That wasn't sarcastic. Literally the first parameter in that page is the formatting provider that determines how the values are formatted. Or you can manually set the formatting.

Comment: I need to use string.Format("{0}", DateTimeInstance) as is. My question is: 1. does the default culture depends on the client connected? 2. If yes, can I override this behavour?

Comment: It can depend on the client if it has been set to depend on it. ASP.NET does have a setting for it in Web.Config's globalization part. It can also be a manual code, or many other things that set it. This is why one shouldn't use formatting without specifying the format if the format has to be specific one.

Comment: I must use format without specific parameters because the application is a part of a programmable system developed in a GMP context. To add a parameter would mean serious changes to the design environment and a new version of the functional specification. Please just accept the fact that the code used cannot be changed. The web config has not been set this way, is this a default behavour? Can you be more precise? "Many other things": can you give some example, some indication, anything useful?

Comment: Can you please create a [MCVE] at least?

Comment: Where did you call `string.Format`? And what is 'DateTimeInstance'?

Comment: The point is that I cannot reproduce the problem. In the server, in a class invoked by an action of a controller, string.Format("{0}", DateTime.Now) returns "15/11/2016 13:02:20" some times, "11/15/2016 13:02:20" other times. I don't know why. This is the question. I am trying to change my client settings to find out it they affect the result, but still don't find any relation between the client settings and default format applied. DateTimeInstance is just any instance of DateTime, let's say DateTime.Now, for example....